# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: "Can't load the profile. Profile Dir:

Tags: python, firefox, selenium-webdriver

How do deal with below error?

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: "Can't load
>   the profile.

[image]

I've tried add my host file like it in [python selenium webdriver issue ( selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: "Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963764/python-selenium-webdriver-issue-selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception)

But it not works, any other ways to solve the problem?

> 127.0.0.1 localhost

```
127.0.0.1 local.development.com
```

Answer (score 2):

I've update selenium site package to the latest one.

by the cmd:

> pip install -U selenium

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`pip install -U selenium`

I had this same issue with `Firefox 34.0.5 (Dec 1, 2014)` and upgrading Selenium from 2.42.1 to 2.44.0 resolved my issue.

However, I've have since seen this issue again, I think with 2.44.0, and another upgrade fixed it.  So I'm wondering if it might be fixed by simply uninstalling and then re-installing.  If so, I'm not sure what that would indicate the underlying problem is.