# Can't run Firefox with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, firefox, ubuntu, selenium

I'm trying to run this code in Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait # available since 2.4.0
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC # available since 2.26.0
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = profile)
# Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
# go to the google home page
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

When I run it, Firefox starts after a while on a blank page, and stays that way.
I get this message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = profile)
  File "/home/fx/EnvDev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=capabilities)
  File "/home/fx/EnvDev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 72, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/fx/EnvDev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 114, in start_session
    'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
  File "/home/fx/EnvDev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 165, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/fx/EnvDev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 152, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: ''
```

I use Firefox 20.0 on Ubuntu 12.04 behind a proxy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selenium: FirefoxProfile exception Can't load the profile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682009/selenium-firefoxprofile-exception-cant-load-the-profile)

Comment: The code works for me without any errors. Try to reinstall selenium and give another try.

Comment: I already did (I install using pip install Selenium).

Comment: Could this problem be caused by a proxy ?

Comment: have you tried without proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest versions of Selenium WebDriver

Selenium Update for Python

1. Open cmd prompt
2. Locate the folder `C:\Python27\Scripts` in cmd
   and enter

> pip install -U selenium

[image]