# Issue with selenium-python on Firefox

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium and am following the website http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/

I tried the following bit of code which is there on the website

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

When I run this program, a Firefox instance opens but never loads the page. [check snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ijPe.jpg)

This is what I have received in the output console

```
C:\Users\Gauss\Desktop>python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "D:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.50.0-py3.5.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 78, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout)
  File "D:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.50.0-py3.5.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\extension_connection.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
  File "D:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.50.0-py3.5.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 68, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable()
  File "D:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.50.0-py3.5.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 106, in _wait_until_connectable
% (self.profile.path))
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: C:\Users\Gauss\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkpjhnhpb If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

Could someone please suggest a solution to this issue?

Note: This issue is on my office pc and the same code works fine on my home pc. So some issue with Firefox maybe.

Comment: Probable duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6682009/954442

Comment: this post mentions that the issue was fixed post version 2.26 but I am using 2.50 still facing this issue, I am working on Windows 10 and Firefox version is 44.0

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, it looks like the version of Firefox you have [is not yet supported](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/py/CHANGES) by python driver. Currently they support up to v. 38, you have 44.

Comment: My home pc also has the Firefox version 44 and Selenium 2.50 but it works fine on that. Issue seems to be on my office pc.