# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, centos, webdriver

I'm using selenium with python to do some automated testing

my code was working correctly until this morning, when I run it it gave me this exception

```
     driver = fwb.WebDriver(firefox_profile=ff_profile, firefox_binary=ff_bin)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 66, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 105, in _wait_until_connectable
    raise WebDriverException("Can't load the profile. Profile "
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: %s If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

I'm working on CentOS release 6.7 (Final), firefox 38.6.0, selenium 2.52

PS: YESTERDAY it was working perfectly, I didn't do any changes, today it crashes

any ideas ?

Comment: possible duplicate :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682009/selenium-firefoxprofile-exception-cant-load-the-profile

Comment: nope, it's not, in my case, the code was working well untill today

Comment: `pip install -U selenium`
this didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was 127.0.0.1 blocked in the firewall of the server.
I don't know how it's blocked, but when I removed it from the firewall, it worked

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround. 
The problem appears because the compatibility check for FF extensions takes more than 30 secounds.
Installing the FF extension "Disable Add-on Compatibility Checks" skips this and everything is fine.