# Selenium: FirefoxProfile exception Can't load the profile, No Browser is open on OSX

Tags: selenium, firefox, robotframework

I've installed my selenium and after run `pybot myTest`, there is error about the profile of firefox.

It's exactly the same issue as this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682009/selenium-firefoxprofile-exception-cant-load-the-profile). Unfortunately I did run `pip install -U selenium` but

it still return the same error, my firefox version is 48.0.1. Here is my errors

```
<msg timestamp="20160824 16:01:19.947" level="INFO">Opening browser 'firefox' to base url 'https://www.google.com'</msg>
<kw name="Capture Page Screenshot" library="Selenium2Library">
<doc>Takes a screenshot of the current page and embeds it into the log.</doc>
<msg timestamp="20160824 16:01:50.167" level="FAIL">No browser is open</msg>
<status status="FAIL" endtime="20160824 16:01:50.167" starttime="20160824 16:01:50.157"></status>
</kw>
<msg timestamp="20160824 16:01:50.167" level="WARN">Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: No browser is open</msg>
<msg timestamp="20160824 16:01:50.168" level="FAIL">WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: /var/folders/b9/th8_45d55_16rlk9wsdfp8300000gn/T/tmppUXVZI/webdriver-py-profilecopy If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
</msg>
```

Any help or suggestion would be very helpful, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Selenium are you running? They have decided to discontinue supporting Firefox and introduced [Marionette](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver). You can either use Marionette or upgrade your Selenium to 2.53.1, i believe that this release was dedicated for the Firefox support. Goodluck!