# Selenium can't load profile (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I'm trying to use Selenium to automate some stuff with Python, but I can't get the website loading. I've been searching for solution but the well answered articles about this topic tend to be 3-5 years old and the answers I've found haven't fixed it so far.

- My OS is Windows 8.1
- Firefox version is 48.0.2
- Selenium version is 2.53.6
- Python version is 3.5.2

I started with the sample code from Selenium's documentation:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

This sadly resulted in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "linkshare_scraper.py", line 30, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\
firefox\webdriver.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\
firefox\extension_connection.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\
firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 68, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable(timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\
firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 108, in _wait_until_connectable
    % (self.profile.path))
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile.
Profile Dir: C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpsmnjuomr If you specified a lo
g_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

Comment: As per @alecxe suggestion: *downgrade Firefox to 47*; source: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39435532/4183498

Comment: Ah, thank you so much. I was searching for an hour but I didn't find that answer.