# Firefox blank webbrowser with selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, firefox

When I call a firefox webbrowser with python firefox webdriver, the firefox is opening with a blank page (nothing in the navigation barre), wait and close.

> The python consol give me this error : Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ```
> File "firefox_selenium2.py", line 4, in <module>
>   driver = webdriver.Firefox()   
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 80, in __init__
>   self.binary, timeout)   
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 52, in __init__
>   self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile, timeout=timeout)   
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 68, in launch_browser
>   self._wait_until_connectable(timeout=timeout)   
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 108, in _wait_until_connectable
>   % (self.profile.path)) 
> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: 
> Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: /tmp/tmpngm7g76x 
> If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
> ```

My code is the exemple from the python selenium read_the_doc :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

Any help would be appreciated

PS : firefox version 49
selenium version 2.53.6
python 3.5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium: FirefoxProfile exception Can't load the profile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682009/selenium-firefoxprofile-exception-cant-load-the-profile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this post
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2739#issuecomment-249479530
the is that you need to use something called Gecko Driver, found here https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. Other people have had success going back to a previous version (before 48) of Firefox as well. I'm also experiencing this problem and don't actually understand how to do either solution and am making slow progress.

Hi Dennis, I'll post my step by step solution now that I got it to work.

## Step By Step solution

The problem is that Selenium and Firefox don't support one another anymore. I don't actually understand why but hopefully someone can comment and explain in more thorough detail than I. There are two possible solutions. One is install something called Geckodriver. I got that installed but had difficulty adding it to my PATH and generally found myself frustrated.

**Instead** I went a simpler route. 
First I uninstalled firefox with the command

```
sudo apt-get purge firefox
```

Then I downloaded [Firefox 47.0.1](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/47.0.1/) from here (I selected the english US version). I then moved it from my downloads folder to my home folder. Then I extracted it using this command.

```
tar xjf firefox-47.0.1.tar.bz2
```

Your number Firefox may be different from mine. Then I cd'd into that directory

```
cd firefox
```

which brought me into that directory. Then all that was left was to run the command

```
sudo apt install firefox
```

After which the version of Selenium I have worked again. Happily I'm back to writing code not configuring things!

Comment: you downloaded and uncompressed Firefox, then ignored it and just installed a different version via the package manager.

Comment: btw, geckodriver is now a requirement for using selenium with recent versions of firefox.

Comment: Thank you all for the great explanation!