# Selenium seems not working properly with Firefox 49.0, Is anyone familiar with this?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I have been trying to load my Firefox (Mozilla Firefox 49.0), with simple python script and with the assistance of selenium-2.53.6 on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, but even [selenium's basic example 0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) doesn't work:

> from selenium import webdriver
>
> browser = webdriver.Firefox()
>
> browser.get('http://seleniumhq.org/')

I always get after about 5 seconds a timeout, and firefox crashes with the following message:

"Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: /tmp/tmpl5qlfokc If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details"

so I created a specific firefox profile (profile -p), and used it, wrote:

> profile =
>   webdriver.FirefoxProfile('absolute path to profile folder')
>
> driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)

but still it seems no matter what I do, the browser crashes after 5 seconds.

Read the post [can't load profile on firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682009/selenium-firefoxprofile-exception-cant-load-the-profile) and followed the instructions but still unfortunately the same result. does anyone know how to overcome this the issue?

Thank you all!

Comment: *The Solution: Apparently the crash can be avoided after installing Selenium 3 (it's in beta stage) thanks to Nima Ghotbi remark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For firefox 49.0 you need selenium 3(it's in beta stage, that's why you can't download it with `pip -U`) and geckodriver.

try this:

```
wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.10.0/geckodriver-v0.10.0-linux64.tar.gz
tar xzvf geckodriver-v0.10.0-linux64.tar.gz
cp geckodriver /usr/bin/
pip install selenium==3.0.0b3
```

Comment: tell me if this solved your problem. don't forget `sudo` :)

Comment: Tried it, worked partially! I indeed stopped getting Firefox crash :), but how come the web-page doesn't get loaded.I have sniffed the interface via wireshark and only a single HTTP request is sent from my interface "http://ocsp.digicert.com". why the http request from my script does not get sent ? quite weird, any explanation?

Comment: never mind I figured out my workspace was not set correctly I have fixed the issue. Thanks again!