# Not being able to navigate using webdriver from Selenium for Python

Tags: python, selenium

Last week I created and ran a test script

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
client = "Python"
if client not in driver.current_url:
    print("Wrong Client")
else:
    print("Continue")
```

Which was working fine, opening a firefox window and navigating to Python.org

Today I have ran both my script and the test one and there I get a timeout error, which means that there is no navigation.

I have tried opening the webpage using

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

and then manually opening Python.org and then running a test

```
client = "Python"
if client not in driver.current_url:
    print("Wrong Client")
else:
    print("Continue")
```

I get an error saying driver not defined, However I had tested this last week and it worked fine.

I am not sure why I am not being able to navigate as the commands have not changed from the script that previously worked.

Below error message from Python

> WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        2 from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
>        3 
>   ----> 4 driver = webdriver.Firefox()
>        5 driver.get("http://www.python.org")
>        6 assert "Python" in driver.title
>
> C:\Users\bca\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py
>   in **init**(self, firefox_profile, firefox_binary, timeout,
>   capabilities, proxy, executable_path, firefox_options)
>       78 
>       79             executor = ExtensionConnection("127.0.0.1", self.profile,
>   ---> 80                                            self.binary, timeout)
>       81             RemoteWebDriver.**init**(
>       82                 self,
>
> C:\Users\bca\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\extension_connection.py
>   in **init**(self, host, firefox_profile, firefox_binary, timeout)
>       50         self.profile.add_extension()
>       51 
>   ---> 52         self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile, timeout=timeout)
>       53         _URL = "http://%s:%d/hub" % (HOST, PORT)
>       54         RemoteConnection.**init**(
>
> C:\Users\bca\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py
>   in launch_browser(self, profile, timeout)
>       66 
>       67         self._start_from_profile_path(self.profile.path)
>   ---> 68         self._wait_until_connectable(timeout=timeout)
>       69 
>       70     def kill(self):
>
> C:\Users\bca\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py
>   in _wait_until_connectable(self, timeout)    106
>   "Dir: %s If you specified a log_file in the "    107
>   "FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details."
>   --> 108                     % (self.profile.path))    109             count += 1    110             time.sleep(1)
>
> WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir:
>   C:\Users\bca\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpzejv0ejm If you specified a
>   log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium: FirefoxProfile exception Can't load the profile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682009/selenium-firefoxprofile-exception-cant-load-the-profile)

Comment: what versions are you using for Firefox and Selenium?

Comment: @sircapsalot I am using Python 3.5.2 Selenium 3.0.1 Firefox 49.0.1 and running the script through Jupyter notebooks from Anaconda 4.2.0

Comment: @RandomDavis I had not seen that answer and it does look like a very similar issue, however from the info the issue should not be happening with the versions I am using. As well I don't see why if I have not updated Firefox since the first time I ran the code and it worked why the problem would be taking place.

Comment: ok, and do you have `geckodriver` properly configured? additionally, there is no `3.0.1` version of selenium.  i'll assume `3.0.0` stable

Comment: @sircapsalot I downgraded firefox and the error that I am getting is regarding the geckodriver as you are mentioning. No sure what the correct configuration should be, so need to look into that.

Comment: @sircapsalot update has taken place for selenium they are no on to 3.0.1 if you check http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Comment: @BDM.  You opened this question two days ago.  3.0.1 was released [just yesterday](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/releases/tag/selenium-3.0.1) :P